# How to get question value per submit in aquiz?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have build simple page for multi choose selection which load data from database with ten question the question is shown one by one in click next what I try to do is to  get question id and answer after  click next to save in database I have manged to get radio button selected value correctly I try to use the same way to catch question id but always null my trial is

my form

```
 @foreach (var v in Model)
            {

                <form class="question-form mt-4" id="q-@count" data-question="@count">

                    <div class="header bg-cyan">
                        <h2>
                            @srno.&nbsp;  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.QuestionTitle)
                        </h2>


                        <input type="text" class="T-@srno" name="T-@srno" value="@v.QuestionId">
                        <input type="hidden" class="T-@srno" name="T-@srno" value="@v.QuestionId">


                        <ul class="header-dropdown m-r--5">
                            <li>
                                مده السؤال - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Questionperiod) ثانيه
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="body">

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                                <label for="opt1-@count">
                                    <input name="group-@srno" type="radio" id="opt1-@count" value="1" />
                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Option1)</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                                <label for="opt2-@count">
                                    <input name="group-@srno" type="radio" id="opt2-@count" value="2"/>
                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Option2)</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                                <label for="opt3-@count">
                                    <input name="group-@srno" type="radio" id="opt3-@count" value="3" />
                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Option3)</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                                <label for="opt4-@count">
                                    <input name="group-@srno" type="radio" id="opt4-@count" value="4" />
                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Option4)</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                                <label for="opt5-@count">
                                    <input name="group-@srno" type="radio" id="opt5-@count" value="5" />
                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Option5)</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-radio">
                                <label for="opt6-@count">
                                    <input name="group-@srno" type="radio" id="opt6-@count" value="6" />
                                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => v.Option6)</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    @if (srno < TotalQuestion)
                    {
                        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link col-sm-12 col-lg-12">التالي</button>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link col-sm-12 col-lg-12" href="@Url.Action("Result","Questions",new {id=v.QuestionId})">إنهاء</a>
                    }
                </form>
                count++;
                srno++;


            }
```

my javascrpit

```
function handleClick() {
    var amountCorrect = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var d = "";

    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        // get radio value
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('group-' + i);
        for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
            var radio = radios[j];
            //if (radio.value == "correct" && radio.checked) {
            //    amountCorrect++;
            //}
            if (radio.checked) {
                 x = radio.value;
                amountCorrect++;
            }
        }

        //debugger;

        var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('T-' + i);
        for (var a = 0; a < questions.length; a++) {
            var question = questions[a];

           d = question.defaultValue;

        }


    }
```

how can I get each question value of current preview one then get the next on the next question and so on

Answer (score 0):

so after check it carefully then I make concatenation inside click that I got the correct question id

```
 $('.question-form #submit').click(function () {

             q += 1;
             questions = document.getElementById('T-' + q).value;

        alert("questions id " + questions + " answer id " + x);

        current = $(this).parent('form:first').data('question');
        next = $(this).parent('form:first').data('question') + 1;
        $('.question-form').hide();
        i++;
        quizId = '#q-' + i;
        $(quizId).fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });
```